# Atlantis repo config for all repos in Organization

Tags: git, github, atlantis

Per https://www.runatlantis.io/docs/server-side-repo-config.html#requiring-pr-is-mergeable-before-apply-or-import Atlantis is requesting to add all repos or specific repos. Is there anyway I can set it to all repos inside a specific Organization? Here is a sample config. Please advise.

```
repos:
  - id: /.*/ # Defaults
    apply_requirements: []
    workflow: default
    allowed_overrides: []
    allow_custom_workflows: false

  - id: github.com/MyOrg/MyRepo1 # Single Repo
    apply_requirements:
      - approved
      - mergeable
    workflow: default
    allowed_overrides:
      - workflow
    allow_custom_workflows: false

  - id: github.com/MyOrg/* # All repos under MyOrg
    apply_requirements:
      - approved
      - mergeable
    workflow: default
    allowed_overrides:
      - workflow
    allow_custom_workflows: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its resolved. The answer is to use regex formatted structure. I have it tested and working.

```
- id: /github\.com/MyOrg/.*/ # All Repos under MyOrg Org
    apply_requirements:
      - approved
      - mergeable
    workflow: default
    allowed_overrides:
      - workflow
```